# Memory Limit Exceed to find N-th prime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving a problem (on a website) to print N-th prime number where N is an user input. The problem fixed those limits 1s, 512 MB. I wrote that code bellow.

```
n = int(input())
r = (n+1)**2
nth = n - 1
d = [x for x in range(2, r)]
non_prime = []
for i in range(2, r):
    for x in d:
        if i % x == 0 and x != 1 and x != i:
            non_prime.append(i)


non_prime = list(set(non_prime))
prime_numbers = [x for x in d if x not in non_prime]
print(prime_numbers[nth])
```

**Now the code works perfectly but after submitting it says Memory Limit Exceeded. How to solve that without changing my code excessively??**

(I know there is much easier way to solve that problem. But I solve it on my own.)

Comment: instead of keeping track of the non-primes, why not just keep track of the primes instead?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to keep track of primes, i was just typing whatever it needs to get a list of primes.

Comment: You keep track of primes the same way you keep track of non primes, except there are _far_ fewer primes so you won't run out of memory

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using checks every number up to the square of a given number. I find it much easier to add prime numbers to a list and check its length. Using this method, it checks few numbers and can run fast.

```
def getPrime(num):
    arr = []
    x = 2
    while len(arr) < num:
        prime = True
        for divisor in range(2, x):
            if x % divisor == 0 and prime == True:
                prime = False
        if prime == True:
            arr.append(x)
        x += 1
    return arr[num - 1]
```

I encourage you improve this code, as it is rudimentary.

Edit: I corrected a variable name.

Comment: I can't understand how to run that code you provided cause I can't pass just a single num to getPrime

Comment: Because it uses a return statement, you have to run it inside a print function to see the result. Alternatively, you could declare a variable with the function and use that variable later on.

Sorry, I used the wrong variable in the return statement, I was transcribing my code line by line and was using different variable names.